# User role (e.g. Admin, User) going into table instead of User Name

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have a comment page, and where I have user roles(Global Admin(3), Admin(2), User(1)), they can all post comments on the page.

My problem is that the user role (1,2, or 3) is put into the table instead of the user name, Any ideas how to fix this? Here is the insert code.

```
<?
include 'dbconnect.php';
$userName = $_SESSION['user'];
$comment = $_REQUEST["comments"];
$game_ID = $_SESSION['id'];
$query = "INSERT INTO comments (userName, comment, page_ID) VALUES ('$userName',     '$comment', '$game_ID')";
mysql_query ($query);
echo "Thanks, your comment has been added!";
include 'close.php';
?>
```

Login Code:

```
$errorMessage = '';
if (!empty($_POST['txtuserName']) && !empty($_POST['txtpassword'])) {
include 'dbconnect.php';


$user   = $_POST['txtuserName'];
$password = $_POST['txtpassword'];

// check if the user id and password combination exist in database
$query = "SELECT userName, password, role FROM member WHERE userName = '$user' AND password = '$password'";

$output = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed. ' . mysql_error()); 
$row = mysql_fetch_array($output);

if (mysql_num_rows($output) == 1 AND $row['role']==1) {
    // the user id and password match, 
    // set the session
    $_SESSION['user'] = true;
    // after login we move to the main page
    header('Location: games.php');
    exit;
}
elseif (mysql_num_rows($output) == 1 AND $row['role']==2) {
    // the user id and password match, 
    // set the session
    $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['user'] = true;
    // after login we move to the main page
    header('Location: games.php');
    exit;
}
elseif (mysql_num_rows($output) == 1 AND $row['role']==3) {
    // the user id and password match, 
    // set the session
    $_SESSION['admin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['user'] = true;
    $_SESSION['global'] = true;
    // after login we move to the main page
    header('Location: listUsers.php');
    exit;
}
else {
    $error = 'The supplied username and/or password was incorrect. Please try again.';
}

include 'close.php';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply place `userName` into the session:

```
$_SESSION['userName'] = $row['userName'];
```

It will then be available in the rest of your application.

Also keep in mind that you can place arrays into the session. So, you'd be able to refactor your code as:

```
$_SESSION['user'] = array('userName'=>$row['userName'], 'role'=>$row['role']);
```

And later in your code:

```
if ($_SESSION['user']['role'] == 2) {
    // allow admin stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `$_SESSION['user'] = true;` but then later trying to access it with `$userName = $_SESSION['user'];` ... Your login code should instead say

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $row['userName'];
```

Your code is inserting the value of `$_SESSION['user']` into the database for `userName`, but unfortunately it's simply setting that to `true` when you log in.

Comment: That's what I was typing when you answered before me!

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks guys! Need to be quicker off the block Frederick lol :)